# Display columns from 2 table , i will detail inside post

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got 2 tables Vehicle and Fueling 
Vehicle : uuid | license_plate
Fueling : vehicle_uuid | fuel_tank
I connect them by uuid=vehicle_uuid ... 
fuel_tank column is boolean and represent if the vehicle has done a full fill of the fuel_tank . I have to display the Vehicles which never full filled their fuel_tank

Example

- Vehicle :

  - id | license_plate
  - 1  | B02ARH
  - 2  | B03ARH
- Fuelling

  - id | fuel_tank
  - 1  | t
  - 1  | f
  - 1  | t
  - 2  | f
  - 2  | f

So it should display only vehicle with id 2 , license_plate : B03ARH

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Google and learn about the EXISTS() / NOT EXISTS() function in SQL.   Or if your database doesn't have EXISTS(), learn about JOINs in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select/filter where your fuel_tank is false (f), then join the tables together, and finally select the fields you want from both tables. This is a basic selection task in SQL.

Start with filtering your data to only the "f" records.

```
Select *
From Fueling
Where uuid not in (Select distinct uuid from Fueling where fuel_tank like "t")
```

Now join the tables. That gives us this:

```
Select 
    veh.*,
    fue.*
From 
    Fueling fue,
    Vehicle veh
Where 
    veh.uuid = fue.uuid AND
    fueuuid not in (Select distinct uuid from Fueling where fuel_tank like "t")
```

Finally, you adjust the select columns to just the columns you want.

```
Select 
    veh.uuid,
    veh.license_plate,
    fue.fuel_tank
From 
    Fueling fue,
    Vehicle veh
Where 
    veh.uuid = fue.uuid AND
    fue.uuid not in (Select distinct uuid from Fueling where fuel_tank like "t")
```

When working with databases, learn to break down your task so you can work out what you need to do in little steps if you are unsure what you need to do.

Comment: This querry will display the cars with f as tank_fuel , but that cars can have a t ( true ) fuel_tank . Examepe , for your querry it will display including B02ARH . I mean , if a car did sometime a full tank fill doesnt matter its rest full_tank values because it become incorect solution ...

Comment: Because this first answer was to show you how to create a SQL statement by breaking it down. I'll update it with the actual solution for your particular question because I've got a few spare minutes.

Comment: Full solution posted. Might take a few minutes for the edit to get approved.